# How can I use a bool in a SwiftUI button?

Tags: swiftui

I want to change the result of the bool `Enabled`, but don't know how to do it.

I need the bool to enable/disable a function in another `UIViewRepresentable`.

Code:

```
import SwiftUI

var Enable = true

struct ContentView: View {

      @State private var Route = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack{

        Button(action: {
                       self.Route.toggle()
                       }) {
                       Text("Route >")
                   }

                   if Route {

                       Enable = false
                  }

          }

    }
}
```

If I use this code it prints the error:

> `Argument type '()' does not conform to expected type 'View'`

Comment: Two noticeable things. First, and probably just some missing code in your question - where are you declaring `Enable`. (BTW, Swift guidelines expect it to be `enabled` as in lowercase. Are you declaring this in a class or a view or just as a singleton? Second, well, your placement of the `if` statement doesn't make sense. What are you actually trying to do? Sync `route` with `enabled`?

Comment: Everything that is inside `body` should be views. the code `Enabled = false` is not a view, like expected and that is causing the error you are asking about. If you want to change `Enable` when the button is pressed, you can add `Enable = self.Route` after `self.Route.toggle()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in comments, by convention, variables should begin with lowercase and types (classes, enum, struct) with uppercase.

Also, your code should go inside the closure.

```swift
var enable = true

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var route = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack{

            Button(action: {
                self.route.toggle()
                if self.route { enable = false }
            }) {
                Text("Route >")
            }
        }
    }
}
```